# Convert 1-band .nc file to GeoTiff with RGB

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, color, rgb

How can I convert 1-band .nc file to GeoTiff with RGB?

I have tried using gdal translate but it won't let me apply color interp of RGB to the .nc as it has 1 band.

Comment: Well, even if you created a RGB-tiff, it still would appear to be greyscale. So why bother?

Comment: Okay well I guess I might not have identified the issue correctly. When I translate the nc to GeoTiff, the greyscale isn't right, it appears oversaturated (compared to plotting the nc in Python)

Comment: If the .nc file is more than 8 bit, then you could look at the -scale parameter of gdal_translate

Comment: the .nc file is Int16

Comment: got min/max for data and applied to translate in Python but didn't work. command : 
gdal.Translate("plswork.tiff", "test_data.nc" , format='GTiff', width=1000, height=1000, scaleParams=[[ 233.605315, 290.90363]])